# Javascript setting off functions with key strokes

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I'm not going to include any code as what I want to ask is pretty easy to understand, lets say I have a function called `StartTimer()`.

And I want to start the timer on the screen by calling the function, but I dont want it to be called when the page loads or something, I want it to be called when a key on the keyboard is pressed, such as <kbd>F9</kbd>. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helps to you.

```
function callFunction(e) {
    //to determine which key is pressed eg:- checking enter key is pressing
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
          StartTimer() //your function is called when enter key is pressed 
                       //Or you can put key code as you want 
    }
}
```

If you want to press key at anywhere of body then you can just do this

```
<body onkeypress="callFunction(event)"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a listener:

```
var listener = function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keycode === 120) { // F9
     StartTimer();
  }
};
```

Then add it to the document:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', listener);
```

Or legacy HTML:

```
document.onkeypress = listener;
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(document).keydown(listener);
```

Comment: sorry, can you tell me which goes where? does the listener go inside <script> tags? or does the document.addeventlistener go inside it